# How to Drag and Drop Files to a DataGridView and record the file names into the cells C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have created a binded DataGridView that has one single column. I want to be able to drag and drop files onto the DataGridView and store only the filenames (Path and Name) into the cells of the column. I have been doing research and the way to do it is to use the events DragDrop and DragEnter and have tried a couple different things but none have worked. Does anyone know how to do this?

My code:

```
   private void PlaylistDataGridDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void PlaylistDataGridDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {      
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (var filePath in files)
            {
                var a = (DataRowView) PlaylistBindingSource.AddNew();
                a.BeginEdit();
                a[0] = filePath;
                a.EndEdit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to implement the [DragEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx) and [DragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx) events like you say. [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-implement-drag-n-drop-in-c-applications/148) is a good article on how to do this. You added your code as I was typing. You just need to adjust how you add items to your DataGridView. You need to add a new row and then address the last row:

```
PlaylistDataGrid.Rows.Add();
PlayListDataGrid[0,PlaylistDataGrid.RowCount-1].Value = filePath
```

This assumes you want to put the data in the first column of the DataGridView.